# Плюсовать значение при событии

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть javascript:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.plus-minus button', function() {
  var btn = $(this),
    oldValue = btn.closest('.plus-minus').find('input').val().trim(),
    newVal = 1;
  if (btn.attr('data-dir') == 'up') {
    newVal = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;
  } else {
    if (oldValue > 1) {
      newVal = parseInt(oldValue) - 1;
    } else {
      newVal = 1;
    }
  }
  btn.closest('.plus-minus').find('input').val(newVal);
});
```

Смысл в том, что на странице интернет-магазина при нажатии кнопок `+` или `-` добавляется или уменьшается количество товара в поле `input`. Но он добавляет всегда `+1` или `-1` к текущему значению. Как переписать его так, чтобы он прибавлял к старому значению это же значение каждый раз?

**Пример**: первоначальное значение = `2`. Нажимаем `+` и добавляется количество товара `+2` (в итоге получается `4`), нажимаем еще `+` и добавляется первоначальное значение к текущему (`4`+`2`) в итоге получаем `6`. С вычитанием такая же логика должна быть - вычитать самое первое значение. Пробовал просто суммировать каждый раз `oldValue` + `oldValue` , но получается что он каждый раз его удваивает.

Comment: Я.. Не совсем понял, что вам нужно. Судя по коду, оно делает именно то, что вам и нужно

Comment: А.. Понял теперь

Comment: Занесите изначальное значение в дата атрибут и берите оттуда для добавления

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
var vl = false;
$(document).on('click', '.plus-minus button', function() {
  var btn = $(this),
    oldValue = btn.closest('.plus-minus').find('input').val().trim(),
    newVal = vl || oldValue;
  vl = newVal;
  if (btn.attr('data-dir') == 'up') {
    newVal = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;
  } else {
    if (oldValue > 1) {
      newVal = parseInt(oldValue) - 1;
    } else {
      newVal = 1;
    }
  }
  btn.closest('.plus-minus').find('input').val(newVal);
});
```